# Is $P(A' \cap B \cap C) = P(A') \times P(B \cap C)$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Is $P(A' \cap B \cap C) = P(A') \times P(B \cap C)$?

Why is $P(A \cap B' \cap C') = P(A) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$ and not equal to $P(A) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is $\mathsf P(A' \cap B \cap C) = \mathsf P(A') \times \mathsf P(B \cap C)$?

Only if $A'$ is independent of $B\cap C$.

> Why is $\mathsf P(A \cap B' \cap C') = \mathsf P(A) - \mathsf P(A \cap B) - \mathsf P(B \cap C) + \mathsf P(A \cap B \cap C)$ and not equal to $\mathsf P(A) - \mathsf P(A \cap B) - \mathsf P(B \cap C) - \mathsf P(A \cap B \cap C)$?

Applications of the Additive Rule for Non-exclusive Events (aka Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion), and deMorgan's Law.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cap B'\cap C') = ~ & \mathsf P(A\cap B')+\mathsf P(A\cap C')-\mathsf P(A\cap (B'\cup C')) \\[1ex] = ~ &  \mathsf P(A\cap B')+\mathsf P(A\cap C')-\mathsf P(A\cap (B\cap C)') \\[1ex] = ~ & (\mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A\cap B))+(\mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A\cap C))-\mathsf P(A\cap (B\cap C)') \\[1ex] = ~ & \mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap C)+(\mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A\cap (B\cap C)')) \\[1ex] = ~ & \mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap C)+\mathsf P(A\cap (B\cap C))\end{align}$$